# The number of rows in the range must be at least 1 google app scripts error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Just not to sure why I am getting this error on google app scripts as this was working fine before. Could someone help me out please?

```
function sendEmailreal() {

 //setup function

 var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1R98Yu-PGAb4FW-WQuVoD0NsQRbmXT32ne1ICZbV8uNs").getSheetByName("Sheet3");
 var StartRow = 2;
 var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
 var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,11);
 var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();


  var link = "<strong>CT IT Feedback link:</strong>"+ "" + "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1naSWINA8_uxeLUsj0lFntqILyDj2nirb56uvkBel79Y/edit#gid=849387835" + "<br><br>"

 var message = "";
 //iterate loop

 for (var i in AllValues) {

 //set current row
 var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];

 //define column to check if sent
 //var EmailSent = CurrentRow[12];

   var check = CurrentRow[11];

   Logger.log(check)

   if ( check == "Complete"){
     return;
 } 


 //set HTML template for information
  message +=

      "<p><b>Timestamp by: </b>" + CurrentRow[0] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Requester Email: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Star Rating: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Request Category: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Description: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Label: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Ticket ID: </b>" + CurrentRow[6] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Comment: </b>" + CurrentRow[7] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Status: </b>" + CurrentRow[8] + "</p><br><br>";
      "<p><b>Complete: </b>" + CurrentRow[11] + "</p><br><br>";

  //set the row to look at
  var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;

  //mark row as "sent"
  //ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 13).setValue("sent");
}

 var SendTo = "thomas.hunt@email.org.au" ;

 //set subject line
 var Subject = "CT IT feedback";


  //send the actual email  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: SendTo,
      cc: "",
      subject: Subject,
      htmlBody: link + message,
});


 };
```

Comment: I'd guess that you don't have any data in your range which makes RowRange=0;

Comment: Oh, silly me, thanks!